# Break JavaScript When run document.forms[0].submit();

Tags: javascript, html

```
onchange="document.forms[0].action = 'policyTypeSelection.do?method=policyTypeSelection'; document.forms[0].submit(); optionCheck(this);">
```

`optionCheck(this);` is Java Script :

```
function optionCheck(frm) {
    var i, len, optionVal, helpDiv, btnStatus,
    selectOptions = document.getElementById("options").submit();

    // loop through the options in case there
    // are multiple selected values
    for (i = 0, len = selectOptions.options.length; i < len; i++) {

        // get the selected option id
        optionVal = selectOptions.options[i].id;

        // find the corresponding help div
        helpDiv = document.getElementById("help");
        Statussecond = document.getElementById("second");
        Statusfirst = document.getElementById("first");

        // move on if we didn't find one
        if (!helpDiv) { continue; }

        // set CSS classes to show/hide help div
        if (selectOptions.options[i].selected) {

            helpDiv.className = "helpTextShow";
            Statussecond.className = "hiddenShow";
            Statusfirst.className = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message? and what's the element fo `document.getElementById("options")`?  It seems that you are triggering a form submission on `document.getElementById("options").submit()` which may be causing you some trouble

Comment: document.getElementById("options")    :  <center class="hidden" id="second">
      <input class="btn" type="submit" name="button" value="xxxx" style="width: 70px" id="button" onclick="return optionCheck(this.form)"/>
            
</center> <div id="help" class="helpText">
                
<div id="box"><h5> Please Wait ... </h5>
         <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
       
<div id="screen">
       </div>   
</div>

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("options").submit() should be changed to
document.getElementsByTagName("option")

and it's unreasonable to submit before checking.
if document.forms[0].submit() submit the form,the page will be reloaded and optionCheck(this) is never executed.